# Placing an element on top of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an accordion using `jQuery` and my code is shared below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#initial .section-content').slideDown();
  
  $('h2').click(function() {
    $('.section-content').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.section-content').slideDown();
  });
})
```

```css
.section-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="initial">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p class="section-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <p class="section-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
  <p class="section-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Section 4</h2>
  <p class="section-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac purus at urna ultrices placerat in a ipsum. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis nibh feugiat, id finibus nisl rutrum. Donec cursus ligula quam, sit amet mollis elit hendrerit quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut sed massa tellus.
  </p>
</div>
```

In this accordion, when I click on each title, it will close other sections open content corresponding to this section.

I want to add more functionality to this accordion. When I click on a heading, corresponding content will be expanded. After that, I want to scroll window such that, the heading on which I clicked appears on top of screen. How can I implement this feature?

Comment: By the way, take a look at jQuery UI's accordion widget: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
This has all the functionality you want out of the box and also has a built-in callback for when the animation is done where you can do the scrolling. There is not much difference compared to what you have achieved already and you would have to include another library in your project, but maybe it is worth a look for you anyway :)

Comment: @EmKay Well. It is true that accordion has functionality that I've already implemented. But it lack scrolling feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the scrolling **after** the opening/closing of the accordion, then you must use the callback function of either your call to slideDown or slideUp.
Documentation for slideDown is here: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/
And for slideUp here: http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

The code could look like this:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $('.section-content').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.section-content').slideDown('slow', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).siblings('h2').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Fiddle where the example above is working can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/s48gx6Lf/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $('.section-content').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.section-content').slideDown('slow', function(){
       $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).siblings('.section-content').offset().top
       }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not working as I expect :( . Can you please share a working demo if it is working for you?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to pass the function as callback of slideDown as it is asynchronous call.